# Cannot connect to AWS MySQL using Java SDK and IAM Role / Instance Profile

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I want to connect to an RDS Aurora instance using an Instance Profile that utilizes STS to assume a role so that I don't need to hard code my password in the solution.  I'm getting an error that states my user doesn't have access.  However, when I hard code the connection string with username and password, I'm able to connect using the same user.  I've checked db user permissions and they're correct.  I've also tried using all permissions in the role.  I've added logging to check that I'm receiving a token and I am.  Any ideas or help is appreciated.  Amazon's documentation that I've been following is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html

My Code:

```
public final class Database {

private static String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + DockerConstants.PersistenceStoreUrl + ":" + DockerConstants.PersistenceStorePort + "/dbname";

private Database() {
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, setMySqlConnectionProperties());
}

static String generateAuthToken(){

    RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
        .credentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance())
        .region(EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion())
        .build();

    String authToken = generator.getAuthToken(
            GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
            .hostname(DockerConstants.PersistenceStoreUrl)
            .port(DockerConstants.PersistenceStorePort)
            .userName(DockerConstants.PersistenceStoreUserName)
            .build());
    return authToken;
}


private static Properties setMySqlConnectionProperties() {
    Properties mysqlConnectionProperties = new Properties();
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate","false");
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("user", DockerConstants.PersistenceStoreUserName);
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("password",generateAuthToken());

    return mysqlConnectionProperties;
}
```

}

Comment: Why the close vote? I am interested in learning more from this solution.

Comment: I am not sure of how new members are managed. I am curious why someone voted to close your question. Of course I am more interested in the problem that you are having and the solution.

Comment: @Dan, have you found any solution for this?